# In spring MVC, is it a good practice to autowire multiple repositories in one service class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I am writing a medium-big web application using Spring as my main framework, I was wondering if I should create a service layer for each repo or if it's a good practice to have one service for multiple repos?

For example, If I have a notes, user and user_notes tables, I am planning to have the notes and user_notes in one service layer, is this a good practice?

Comment: Yes it is! Or maybe not... There's no rule of thumb here, this depends on many different things, and on the taste of the developer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

It's no good practice to have countless empty-ish services without proper reason to exist on their own and it's no good practice to have classes (be it a service or something else) with multiple responsibilities. Will interacting with `ServiceA` automatically mean that you'll also interact with `ServiceB` in the next few lines? Maybe those could be merged. Only using parts of a large service? Check whether splitting into smaller parts makes sense.

When you look at it that way and you decide that a `UserNotesManagingServiceThingy` is a unit then do it. If not then split it. The first person to look at your design will feel the opposite way about it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally speaking every domain entity should have a service of its own. When any use case requires fetching data from multiple entities then there should be a *facade service* at the top of all these entities. This facade will responsible for invoking all the entities below it in order.

Next important part will be to collate the data from all these services  as required by the use case which will typically be dictated by the view design or in case of a restful api - the schema of your response.

To carry this collated data from service to controller one should create DTOs(Data Transfer Objects) which are made for specific use cases. However, DTOs should not be ideally used as form backing beans. They should only be used for carrying data across the layers and handing it over to the Controller method.

Mapping from DTO to UI specific form-backing beans should be done in a ViewHelper or as a private method in the Controller.

So the flow is **UI/View(form-backing Beans) > Controller > (DTO) > Service >(Model)> DAO > DB and the same in reverse**.

Service here can be a facade and can be expanded to **Facade Service > multiple services** as explained above. Doing delegation to multiple services through a facade also helps in managing transactions in a better way.

To answer your specific question about notes, user_notes and user entities - it seems there should be two services UserService and NotesService. You can have methods like FetchNotesByUserId() in NotesService and the other way around in UserService just-in-case your User and Notes have a many-to-many relationship.